# String Value is not passing correctly

Tags: vba, ms-word, data-conversion

I have a word table. I wrote a macro to get values from the table. When it runs I get a runtime error 13. When I debug and watch the value of parsing string it looks like this **"2019-04-03** There is only one quote in the string. I think that is the case I couldn't convert that string into a date format. Can you help me to fix this?

#### The code

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim days As String
    Dim endDate As String

    If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    NumRows = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count

    'Loop to select each row in the current table
    For J = 2 To NumRows
        'Loop to select each cell in the current row
            startDate = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(5).Range.Text
            days = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(6).Range.Text
            FormatDate = CDate(ends)
            endDate = DateAdd("d", days, FormatDate)
            Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(7).Range.Text = endDate
    Next J
End Sub
```

#### The table

[image: This is the word Table]

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I'd suggest putting `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module and compiling.  That way the compiler will show you, for example, that `ends` is only used in one place :) .  For trimming strings, the Mid and Trim functions may be useful.

Comment: I tried those but didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the minimal change I found that works for me when tested in Word 2013.

General points:

- I added `Option Explicit` so that the computer would help me find errors.  In this case, the variables `J` and `FormatDate` were used but not `Dim`ed, and `ends` was used but never initialized (I changed it to `startDate`).
- The `Range.Text` in a table cell includes whitespace and the end-of-table marker (`¤`).  That is why `CDate` was giving an error.

  - For the dates, I used `Left()` to take only the left ten characters, since you seem to always be using `yyyy-mm-dd`-format dates.
  - For the counts of days, since those can be of any length, I used `Range.Words(1).Text` to keep only the first `Word` (as MS Word defines it), which is the number.
- I also added the `CLng()` call in the parameter to `DateAdd`, since `DateAdd` wants a number<sup>*</sup> rather than a string.

For production use, I would also recommend using Selection only in one place, and doing `Dim workTable as Table: Set workTable = Selection.Tables(1)`.  That will simplify your code.

#### Code

`<===` marks changed lines

```
Option Explicit ' <==

Sub Macro2()
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim days As String
    Dim endDate As String

    If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    NumRows = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count

    'Loop to select each row in the current table
    Dim J As Long   ' <==
    For J = 2 To NumRows
        'Loop to select each cell in the current row
            startDate = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(5).Range.Text
            startDate = Left(startDate, 10) ' <== Remove the space and table mark
            days = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(6).Range.Words(1).Text     ' <===
            Dim FormatDate As Date          ' <==
            FormatDate = CDate(startDate)   ' <== not `ends`
            endDate = DateAdd("d", CLng(days), FormatDate)      ' <=== clng
            Selection.Tables(1).Rows(J).Cells(7).Range.Text = endDate
    Next J
End Sub
```

<sup>* `DateAdd` actually takes a `Double`, but VBA can promote `Long` to `Double`.  I chose `CLng` since it looks like you are only using integer day spans.  If not, use `CDbl` instead.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim r As Long
With Selection
  If Not .Information(wdWithInTable) Then Exit Sub
  With .Tables(1)
    For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
      .Cell(r, 7).Range.Text = _
        Format(DateAdd("d", Split(.Cell(r, 6).Range.Text, vbCr)(0), CDate(Split(.Cell(r, 5).Range.Text, vbCr)(0))), "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Next r
  End With
End With
End Sub
```